# synonyms in elasticsearch not matching a phrase with plurals

Tags: elasticsearch

Seeing a strange behaviour with synonyms on Elasticsearch:

Let's say my synonyms file has the following:

```
orange => apples & oranges
```

When I search for orange:

```
POST my_index/_search
{
  "suggest" : {
    "name_suggest" : {
      "text" : "orange",
      "completion" : {
        "field" : "name_suggest",
        "size" : 7,
        "fuzzy" :{}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

it does not match a doc with the name "apples & oranges"

However, if I search for "apples &"

```
POST new_sector_index,org_index/_search
{
  "suggest" : {
    "name_suggest" : {
      "text" : "apples &",
      "completion" : {
        "field" : "name_suggest",
        "size" : 7,
        "fuzzy" :{}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

it does match the doc with the name 'apples & oranges'

I cannot understand why 'orange' does not match even when I have defined the synonym in the file. I know the synonyms are indexed correctly since the other synonyms in the same file are working.

Also, wanted to mention that I am using a synonym_analyzer with `lowercase`, `stop` and `kstem` filters and `whitespace` tokenizer. I could imagine apples & oranges being stemmed to 'apple', '&' , 'orange' and hence not matching  but in that case just the phrase 'apples &' shouldn't match either?

Comment: Try defining your synonym like this instead: `orange, apples & oranges` otherwise `orange` gets replaced

Comment: @Val I did intend `orange` to get replaced with `apples & oranges` and then the doc with the name 'apples and oranges' to be returned but that doesn't happen. However, if I search for 'apples & oranges' it does return 'apples & oranges'

Comment: If you replace `orange` by `apples & oranges` the document cannot be suggested when searching for `orange` since the field doesn't start with `orange` anymore.

Comment: but as I understand it, in a `completion suggester` if I use a `synonym analyzer`, the query does not have to mandaorily start with the field to be matched. For example: `kiwi, grape => fruit` work fine in the completion suggester (i.e searching for `kiwi` returns `fruit`)

Comment: looks like ampersand was the issue. If I do `oranges => apples` in the synonym, it matches 'apples and oranges' correctly. Not sure of the exact reason though.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of ampersand (&) was causing the strange behaviour.

If I just do the following in the synonyms file,

```
orange => apples
```

it returns the intended document with the name 'apples & oranges' correctly

Not sure why `apples & oranges` in the synonyms does not work though. I tried removing `stop` and `kstem` filters but the behaviour remains the same

Comment: What about just `orange` since that was the original culprit?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `orange => apples` works - have updated the answer (so we don't compare apples with oranges :D)